# How can I integrate a machine learning algorithm in py file into django website?

Tags: python, html, django, csv, machine-learning

I'm working with random forest algorithm to predict college dropouts with python, the algorithm is finished and now I have to use that file and be able to run it from a website, I'm using django but I don't know how I can make it work, I import the file in views but it only display a line, it doesn't even have an structure like it has when I run the file in jupyter, so if anyone knows something I'll be very thankful.

Sorry if is a little difficult to understand, english is not my first language.

This is the algorithm

```
 import numpy as np
    from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier 
    from sklearn import metrics
    import pandas as pd
    from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest

    dataset = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/danni/OneDrive/Documents/Universidad/2018/Tesis/encuestas/Nueva carpeta/Nueva carpeta/SinRanking/2005_2017_SOLO_PRIMERO_Y_SEGUNDO.csv',  delimiter=";")  


    datos2 = dataset['F_Nac']
    i = 0
    a = []
    while i < len(datos2):
        value2 = datos2[i]
        first = value2[6:10]

        year = first
        a_ingreso = dataset['A_Ingreso']
        a.append(a_ingreso[i] - int(year)) 
        i += 1
    dataset['edad_ingreso']=a;



    #calculamos la edad de ingreso a la universidad
    def calcula_dif_years_eg_in(anio,cuando):
        return anio - cuando

    dataset['a_egresado_colegio']=dataset.apply(lambda x: calcula_dif_years_eg_in(x['A_Ingreso'],x['A_Egreso_Colegio']), axis=1);


    dataset = dataset.drop(["F_Nac","A_Ingreso","A_Egreso_Colegio","Via_Ingreso"], axis=1)


    # cargamos las variables predictoras
    predictors = dataset.drop(['Deserto'], axis=1)
    # y estos son los resultados que se obtienen, en el mismo orden
    targets = dataset['Deserto']


    best=SelectKBest(k=10)
    X_new = best.fit_transform(predictors, targets)
    X_new.shape
    selected = best.get_support(indices=True)
    print(predictors.columns[selected])



    #datos desde el 2005 al 2015
    X_train = predictors[0:567] 
    X_test = predictors[568:632] 
    #datos del 2016
    y_train = targets[0:567] 
    y_test = targets[568:632]



    modelo = RandomForestClassifier(
     random_state      = 1,   # semilla inicial de aleatoriedad del algoritmo
     n_estimators      = 5, # cantidad de arboles a crear
     min_samples_split = 0.5,   # cantidad minima de observaciones para dividir un nodo
     min_samples_leaf  = 8,   # observaciones minimas que puede tener una hoja del arbol
     n_jobs            = -1    # tareas en paralelo. para todos los cores disponibles usar -1
     )
    modelo.fit(X_train[predictors.columns[selected]].values, y_train)


    prediccion = modelo.predict(X_test[predictors.columns[selected]].values)

    modelo.score(X_train[predictors.columns[selected]], y_train)


    modelo.score(X_test[predictors.columns[selected]], y_test)



    print(metrics.classification_report(y_true=y_test, y_pred=prediccion))
    print(pd.crosstab(y_test, prediccion, rownames=['REAL'], colnames=['PREDICCION']))


    var_imp = pd.DataFrame({
     'feature':predictors.columns[selected], 
     'v_importance':modelo.feature_importances_.tolist()
     })
    print (var_imp.sort_values(by = 'v_importance', ascending=False))




    #Curvas de aprendizaje
    from sklearn.learning_curve import learning_curve

    train_sizes, train_scores, test_scores = learning_curve(estimator=modelo,
                            X=X_train, y=y_train, 
                            train_sizes=np.linspace(0.1, 1.0, 10), cv=10,
                            n_jobs=-1)

    train_mean = np.mean(train_scores, axis=1)
    train_std = np.std(train_scores, axis=1)
    test_mean = np.mean(test_scores, axis=1)
    test_std = np.std(test_scores, axis=1)


    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import seaborn as sns
    get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')
    sns.set_palette("deep",desat=.6)
    sns.set_context(rc={"figure.figsize":(8,4)})

    # graficando las curvas
    plt.plot(train_sizes, train_mean, color='r', marker='o', markersize=5,
             label='entrenamiento')
    plt.fill_between(train_sizes, train_mean + train_std, 
                     train_mean - train_std, alpha=0.15, color='r')
    plt.plot(train_sizes, test_mean, color='b', linestyle='--', 
             marker='s', markersize=5, label='evaluacion')
    plt.fill_between(train_sizes, test_mean + test_std, 
                     test_mean - test_std, alpha=0.15, color='b')
    plt.grid()
    plt.title('Curva de aprendizaje')
    plt.legend(loc='upper right')
    plt.xlabel('Cant de ejemplos de entrenamiento')
    plt.ylabel('Precision')
    plt.show()



    i = 0
    a = []
    while i < len(X_test):
        a.append(modelo.predict(X_test[predictors.columns[selected]])[i]) 
        i += 1


    print(a)


    X_test['x']=a

    X_test
    print(X_test.groupby('x').size())
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options.

1. Run it as a separate service, so that more than one application(s) can use it independently. For this you'll need to create an API around your machine learning implementation (which should expose required functionalities like training a model, predicting etc) and deploy/host it separately. This separates concerns for your web application and the actual machine learning so this is my preferred way unless the whole application is small (like a proof of concept).
2. Keep all the code together including your machine learning part of it and deploy it as a single monolithic application. You'll need some persistent binary (eg. file) storage to store trained models (eg Google cloud storage), from where more than one applications (with their own ML programs, which may differ, maintaining compatibility with your trained model though, if they want to share it). If all you care about is getting something in a working condition first (such as a proof of concept), this should be simpler and faster.